# How can I access values on the UI thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have no issues invoking actions on UI controls through `BeginInvoke` and such, however, that's a `void` method. I need to get a value from a textbox for use in a different thread.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to capture a local variable in a closure.

```
String text;
textBox.Invoke(() => text = textBox.Text);
```

The compiler will generate some code that is much like chibacity's solution - the local variable becomes a field of a compiler-generated class.

**UPDATE**

This does not work - the lambda expression is not assignable to `Delegate`. This problem can be solved using an extension method.

```
internal void ExecuteOnOwningThread(this Control control, Action action)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.Invoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

The usage is then as follows.

```
String text;
textBox.ExecuteOnOwningThread(() => text = textBox.Text);
```

It is possible to stuff multiple statements into the lambda expression.

```
textBox.ExecuteOnOwningThread(() =>
{
    DoStuff();
    text = textBox.Text
    DoOtherStuff();
});
```

But as chibacity already mentioned in a comment it may be better to explicitly write a method. Beyond a certain point using lambda expressions will adversely affect the readability of the code. And using lambda expressions is of course very prone to introducing repeated code.

Comment: Whilst having the one-liner is cute, eventually you're going to be doing more than setting the variable e.g. tell another thread there is some data ready. Having a method to stuff this into is the way to go.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you - for one, two, or maybe three statements that are not repeated several times I would consider using a lambda expression but beyond that using a separate method yields the better code.

Answer (score 4):

The Control.Invoke() method returns the value of the invoked method.  Which makes it easy:

```
        string value = (string)this.Invoke(new Func<string>(() => textBox1.Text));
```

Or a bit more explicit:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        var dlg = new Func<string>(GetText);
        string value = (string)this.Invoke(dlg);
    }
    private string GetText() {
        return textBox1.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a delegate to Invoke that points to a method which can set an instance variable to hold the text value, e.g.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Invoke(new Action(SetTextboxTextVariable));
    }

    private string _text;

    private void SetTextboxTextVariable()
    {
        _text = txtBox.Text;
    }
```

This covers the basic idea, synchronizing and notifying other threads is up to you. :)

**Update**

Or to do it in one step:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string text = GetText();
    }

    private string GetText()
    {
        string text;

        Invoke(new Action(text = txtBox.Text));

        return text;
    }
```